# how to add custom prerequisite for a remote client in a clickonce installer?

Tags: deployment, clickonce, directx

i made a click once installer, in that i added direct X as a custom prerequisite. when i make the installer on my local machine only then the installation of DirectX works fine.   but i need to make a clickonce deployment for the web so that a person can remotely access my installer and download it.

when i am adding a custom prerequisite direct X then i want that my installer should start  downloading direct X in her machine and installs it. how to do this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click Once installers are self-contained.  This hinders the risk of tampering with the application's contents (assuming of course the users trust you as the publish).

You will have to bundle the DirectX files **within** your ClickOnce package.